# How to pass date back to parent class and change label?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uidatepicker

I'm writing a simple inventory app. It uses a **navigation controller** and the `rootViewController` is a `UITableView`. When you click on one of the rows in the `tableView`, it takes you to a `detailsViewController`, where it displays details of the item that was selected. At the bottom of this `detailsViewController` is a `UILabel` that displays the date that the time was created, along with a button that allows you to change the date. When this button is clicked, it pulls up another view controller with a `datePicker`.

How do I get the date label in the `detailsView` to display the new date that the user has picked?

Here's my attempt below. I'm relatively new to iOS programming so this will probably be a simple fix.

```
@implementation MPDetailViewController

- (IBAction)changeDate:(id)sender {
    MPDateViewController *dated = [[MPDateViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dated animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

MPItem *item = self.item;
self.nameField.text = item.itemName;
self.serialNumberField.text = item.serialNumber;
self.valueField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", item.valueInDollars];

//turns a date into a simple string
if (!self.dateFormatter) {
    self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    self.dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    }
self.dateLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:item.dateCreated];
}
```

And this is the date view controller

```
@implementation MPDateViewController

- (IBAction)dateWasChanged:(id)sender {
    self.nDate = [self.changeDate date];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.nDate);
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    MPItem *item = self.item;
    item.dateCreated = self.nDate;
    super.dateLabel.text = [super.dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.nDate];
}
```

I'd appreciate any help or comments that you are willing to provide.

Comment: you have to go by protocol or by register event for backward process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the Protocol for it. As Protocol is best practice to use in this kind of situation.

Here you can find the document for [Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).

```
@protocol MPDateSelectedDelegate

- (void) MDPDateChanged: (NSDate*) date;

@end
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MPDateSelectedDelegate> delegate;
```

You can call above delegate method when you change the date:

```
[self.delegate MDPDateChanged: newDate];
```

And You have to implement the same method in parent controller like this:

```
- (void) MDPDateChanged: (NSDate*) date
{
    // Do you stuff at here.
    // date will hold the new changed date from picker view.
    NSLog(@"%@",date.description);
}
```

Comment: Alright so I've done everything that the two of you have said, but when you say "//Do your stuff here" what exactly are you suggesting I do? I guess I'm just not getting which line of code I need to write that actually changes the dateLabel once I've done all this delegate/protocol stuff

Comment: You get the date which you select on date picker.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using IBActions to try and get User Interface events which occur in two different view controllers. Unfortunately this does not work. The easiest way (to me at least) to get information between two view controllers is to use delegates.

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm) is a tutorial on how to use delegates.

What you could do is:

Change: `@implementation MPDetailViewController`
To: `@implementation MPDetailViewController <MPDateViewControllerDelegate>`

Add the following lines to your `MPDateViewController.h`

```
@protocol MPDateViewControllerDelegate

- (void) MPDateViewControllerDidChangeDate: (NSString*) date; //I don't know your datatype here, but you can use it as an argument. I'm using NSString as an example

@end
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MPDateViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Finally, add this line once you do change your date in the DateViewController

```
[self.delegate MPDateViewControllerDidChangeDate: newDate];
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Alright so I've done everything that the two of you have said, but when you say "//Do your stuff here" what exactly are you suggesting I do? I guess I'm just not getting which line of code I need to write that actually changes the dateLabel once I've done all this delegate/protocol stuff

Comment: So assuming that you have a NSDate object, you can get a string value for date (date.description, as Nirmit pointed out) said, and then use dateLabel.text = dateString. That's about it. If you want a specific format, I would suggest looking into NSDateFormatter (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)